# Postfix - Is submission (587) enough?

Tags: email, postfix, email-server

I have a working postfix/dovecot solution in place and am ready to update DNS to adjust MX priority away from google MX servers to our server. But I got to thinking, do I NEED to configure postfix to listen on port 25 as well as port 587?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, yes.

The submission port is for client-to-server traffic. Port 25 is for server-to-server traffic.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I set :587 as the goto port at the application layer for users who use the web based email GUI (roundcube) and for app functionality like sending emails when a new user signs up, I thought perhaps this would work for server-to-server as well.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to serve your system as MX, you *need* port 25 and you likely don't need port 587 except your authenticated users should use this to drop off mail authenticated.